solr indexing - drop indexing if field has only spaces
I am trying to index data from HDFS into solr collection using MapReduceIndexerTool. In array field, if an element is empty i.e contains only space no need to index into solr collection.
Input: names:["new york","United states"," "] Output: names:["new york","United states"]
what  i need to add in Morphline config file?
I tried to indexing data using below option in morphline but failed.
{ removeValues { nameBlacklist:["*"] valueBlacklist:["literal:\s"] } }
